Access On Premise Database using Azure Pipelines with MS hosted agents
How can I access an on Premise Database (to be able to use EF core migrations) using Azure DevOps Pipelines with MS hosted agents for the build process?
MS do not allow the usage of VPN between Azure and my on-premise service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml:
"You cannot use private connections such as ExpressRoute or VPN to connect Microsoft-hosted agents to your corporate network. The traffic between Microsoft-hosted agents and your servers will be over public network."
So, my question is, how can I securely enable the communication so that Azure DevOps Pipeline can reach out my on premise database?

You can install a self-hosted agent on a machine that has access to your on-premise database.

As you quoted already, this is not possible with Microsoft-hosted agents. The answer are self-hosted agents. There you can do whatever you like, networking-wise. They could even run onprem.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#self-hosted-agents

If you don't want to use self-hosted agent as suggested in the answer, and still want to use Microsoft-hosted agents, you might need to consider moving your database to a location that can be accessed over the public network, such as Azure SQL Database.  Here is the Migration guides for your reference.
However, this would involve migrating your database from on-premises to the cloud, and whether this is feasible depends on your specific situation.
